# update city in csv file based on zip merge from another file

Tags: python, merge

I have csv file file1.csv

```
Territory   Sales     Zipcode    city   statename
00001000      10         99764
```

Another file with city details

```
Zipcode   city      Statename 
99764     Northway   Alaska
```

I want to update file1.csv like below

```
Territory   Sales     Zipcode    city      statename
00001000      10         99764   Northway   Alaska
```

Its like typical update statement in SQL

```
UPDATE file1 SET file1.value = (SELECT table2.CODE
                                  FROM file2 
                                  WHERE table1.value = table2.DESC)
```

How can i do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to or don't want to install `pandas`, you can use the `csv` module instead. Note the use of an intermediate dict `d2` to map zipcodes to cities and state names from `file2.csv`:

```
with open('file1.csv') as file1, open('file2.csv') as file2, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    output = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
    d2 = {zip: cols for zip, *cols in csv.reader(file2, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)}
    for *cols, zip in csv.reader(file1, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
        output.writerow([*cols, zip, *d2.get(zip, [])])
```

Given `file1.csv` the following content:

```
Territory   Sales     Zipcode    city   statename
00001000      10         99764
00001001      11         99999
```

And given `file2.csv` the following content:

```
Zipcode   city      Statename
99764     Northway   Alaska
99999     Somewhere  CoolState
```

`output.csv` will have the following content:

```
Territory Sales Zipcode city statename
00001000 10 99764 Northway Alaska
00001001 11 99999 Somewhere CoolState
```

Also note that since city names and state names can contain white spaces, you should avoid using spaces as a delimiter and switch to actual commas instead, in which case you can remove the `delimiter=' '` parameter from the `csv.writer` call.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
df = pd.merge(file1,file2,how='left', on = 'Zipcode')
df.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

The files you've given are not properly formatted DSV files, because they contain multiple spaces. Each column of a DSV file needs to be separated by a **single** special character (like ) in your example.

I'm using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) in this example, but because Pandas sometimes has troubles using spaces as separators, I converted your files like the following:

`file1.csv`

```
Territory,Sales,Zipcode
00001000,10,99764
```

`file2.csv`

```
Zipcode,city,Statename 
99764,Northway,Alaska
```

A script that would utilize Pandas to write to `file3.csv` would look like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load both files via pandas
file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=',')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', sep=',')

# Merge results and save them
merge = file1.merge(file2, on='Zipcode')
merge.to_csv('file3.csv', sep=',', index=None)
```

You could also use `sep=' '`, but I would advise against it, since your DSV files are broken, as pointed out before.